# INSERT value from another table and variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am wondering if it is possible to insert from another table (which I have managed to do) whilst also inserting a VALUE of a variable from the current php file?

I am aiming to get the user ID from another table, which I have gotten from selecting the email from the user input. I then need to insert a hash which is automatically created via a variable.

This is my current code that gets the correct id from the users table.

```
$forgot = $pdo->prepare("
                        INSERT INTO
                          forgot (
                              user_id
                          ) SELECT
                              id
                          FROM
                              users
                          WHERE
                              email = :email
");
```

Now I just need to insert the VALUE of :hash too.

Would this need to be done with a separate query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO
forgot (
    user_id, hash
) SELECT
    id, :hash
FROM
    users
WHERE
    email = :email
```

Comment: That worked great thank you, I didn't believe this would work as I thought it would try and select the hash from the other table, whereas there is no column for hash